# Unable to get maximum resolution from external display

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, resolution, dvi

I have a mid 2012 macbook pro running Yosemite and a Dell 2007WFP 30" monitor for an external display.  I previously had connected the DVI cable to the monitor and a PC and was able to get the full resolution.

However, when I take the DVI cable and connect a Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter and plug this into my macbook pro, I'm not able to use the full resolution of the screen.  I go into System Preferences > Display and the greatest resolution I can get is 1280 x 800.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Does your adapter have, by any chance, fewer pins than what the monitor port has? From http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32524/whats-the-difference-between-hdmi-and-dvi-which-is-better/: "Some DVI cables or ports may include fewer pins if they are designed for lower resolution devices, so you’ll need to watch for this.  If your port contains all the pins, however, it can support the max resolution with no problem."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a dual-link DVI adapter, instead of a single-link DVI adapter. After reading many forums from multiple places, it sounds like that's the problem you're having. I found a post from Apple that you can read [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201927)

The title of the forum post states your exact problem, and I saw the same thing being said on a few other forums (non-Apple forums)